# Oracle - how to replace and sum from the output?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, output

I have output of group by as below.

```
SELECT param2,count(*) FROM table WHERE CALLED='1234' GROUP BY PARAM2 

Param2                      count(*)  
135;                          616  
135;135;                       18  
135;135;135;                    4  
135;135;135;135;                2  
135;135;135;135;135;135;27;    15      
135;135;135;27;                 5  
136;                           43  
136;136;                      383  
136;136;136;                   47    
136;136;136;27;                32
```

Expected: For all the output param2 that includes 135 or 136 should be group by once again such that result should be as below:

```
Param2     count(*)  
135        660    
136        505
```

Comment: What is the logic of your expected output ?

Comment: sounds to me that with a simple SQL will not do. Need a sql block. Go every row, split and put each value into a different table, then do this select. Or, simply keep addin to array, because index can be a unique value

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, I have 1000s of records where client can input multiple occurrence of same value in param2 but for me it's single. So I want to dynamically count multiple occurrence as single.

Comment: Ok you mean it is not limited to 135 or 136 but in your example `27` can also appear in output as count `52`? Otherwise the answer provided is what you need as I understood.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30. Yes exactly. 135 or 136 is just an example and within multiple 135 or 136 some other value like 27 can also appear. Actually, solution provided by Mr. Erich is perfect in case values like 135 136 is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications...may I know which version of Oracle are you using ?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given example, a simple straight-forward solution would do the job. Not sure if this is as general as necessary:

```
select '135' as "Param2", count(*) from table
  where called = '1234' and ';'||param2 like '%;135;%'
union all
select '136' as "Param2", count(*) from table
  where called = '1234' and ';'||param2 like '%;136;%'
```

Comment: I think, he needs dynamic, that will count all records

Comment: @Erich Kitzmueller, thanks for your solution. It would be more helpful if it's possible to make it dynamic as '135' and '136' is just an example. I have bulk of such data.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query,

Keeping my base source as the output you have mentioned ,we can use traditional `regular expression` to split the row and get `distinct` values present for `param2` and then a `sum` over it would give the result as expected. I am little skeptical about how the performance will be but you can give it a try.

**with sample data:**

```
with table1
as
(
select '135;' param2, 616 cnt from dual union all
select '135;135;', 18 from dual union all
select '135;135;135;', 4 from dual union all 
select '135;135;135;135;', 2 from dual union all
select '135;135;135;135;135;135;27;', 15 from dual union all      
select '135;135;135;27;', 5 from dual union all
select '136;', 43 from dual union all
select '136;136;', 383 from dual union all  
select '136;136;136;', 47 from dual union all 
select '136;136;136;27;', 32 from dual
)
select split,sum(cnt) cnt
  from 
    (select distinct t1.*, regexp_substr(param2,'[^;]+', 1, level) split
       from table1 t1;
     connect by regexp_substr(param2, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null)
group by split;
```

So the final query should be ,

```
with table1 
as
(
 select param2, count(*) cnt 
   from table 
  where called = '1234' 
 group by param2
)
select split as param2,sum(cnt) cnt
  from 
    (select distinct t1.*, regexp_substr(param2,'[^;]+', 1, level) split
       from table1 t1;
     connect by regexp_substr(param2, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null)
group by split;
```

Comment: Thanks Sujit. But your query is specifically only for the given example. As I said, it's only example and there are lot more like 135 or 136

Comment: No it's general, just replace your query in the `with` clause by removing the static values I took as my source for test purpose.

Comment: @Raazan Kurunju, I edited my answer. Could you check now ?

Comment: It worked as exactly as I required. However, as you claimed about performance, it took lots of time. Firstly I tried with 100K records and waited for 4 hours, then I tried with 500 records that took 3 mins. So, I concluded based on the logic used in this code, the output time increase exponentially.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Raazan Kurunju, Thanks for your feedback. you could opt for PL/SQL to use `bulk collect` and `limit`. May I know when you say `100K` or `500` records, is it `after group by` or `before group by` ?

Comment: I am quite sure for 500 it wont take 3 minutes if I talk about the records after `group by`. will you then hard code values to resolve issue ? I am fine though.

Comment: Here, the 500 records is am talking about i before group by. The delay may be caused by non indexed data. However, the provided solution best worked for me. Rather than making my requirement more complex, i went for group by result to temp table then again work on it.